# function that counts to x then starts over [python]

Tags: python-3.x

Super beginner here, trying to figure something out, please bear with me.

I want to make a function which returns a number that is incremented each time it has been called. When number, in this case 10, is reached, start over counting from 0 to 10. So far I have this code:

```
a = 0

def count():
    global a
    if (a >= 0 | a < 10):
        a = a + 1
    else:
        a = 0
    return a
```

This gives the following output when calling the function 11 times.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
0
```

I can't seem to figure out how to start counting with the number 0. Maybe my whole way of thinking is wrong here, can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Im trying to get different elements in a json response each time a user presses a button in tkinter. The function selects the element in the response like this `request = requests.get(BASE_URL + json_data['results'][count()]['image'])`. The response/request only has 10 elements, so I want it to start over after the button has been clicked 10 times.

Thanks for your response, I hope this explains it a bit.

Comment: I don't think this line: `(a >= 0 | a < 10)` will make it into your final code, but I will just point out to you for education purposes, that every number is either greater than 0 or less than 10. That expression will always evaluate to `True`.

Comment: `a` is first initialized to 0. At the very first call you increment it and then return its new value, i.e. one. Something shouls be changed in this chain.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
def count():
    global a
    if (a >= 0 | a < 10):
        a = a + 1
    else:
        a = 0 
        a= a+1; // add this, or simply, a=1;

    return a
```

Comment: Oh my.. This hurts. Thank you for helping me see my mistake!

Comment: This expression: `(a >= 0 | a < 10)` will always evaluate to `True`. All numbers are either greater than 0 or less than 10. Also, using a `global` is a bad idea, because then other parts of the code can alter the value of `a`. The solution should probably use `yield`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `%`

```
a = 0
def count_till_10():
    global a
    ret = a % 11
    a += 1
    return ret
```

Invoking the first time gives 0. And rolls over to 0 after 10.

Comment: why leave a global variable there? bad habit

Comment: `a` could increase without bound, consuming all the memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can usefully generalise it so that you have a variable for the maximum count, which can be used to initialise the counter:

```
maxCount = 10
a = maxCount

def count():
    global a
    a = (a + 1) % (maxCount + 1)
    return a
```